# Shorten a long enum name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

This is a strange question, but bear with me...

So I am using a third-party library where it uses a very long enum name, like:

`ALongClassName.ALongPublicEnumType.ALongAndVerboseEnumName`

And since I need to compare a `code` to each enum value, I am wondering there is a way for me to shorten the enum name somehow for readability, eg:

`code == Event.Success`

instead of:

`code == ALongClassName.ALongPublicEnumType.ALongAndDescriptiveEnumName`

Comment: The actual ones are around 80-100 characters. But I agree it's just for my own sanity...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `using` alias to achieve this.

At the top of your class, you can do:

```
using Event = ALongClassName.ALongPublicEnumType.ALongAndVerboseEnumName;
```

You can then use it like

```
code == Event.Success
```

Comment: How does he alias `ALongAndVerboseEnumName` to `Success`?

Comment: A dirty trick might be using a static variable.  

`var Success = ALongClassName.ALongPublicEnumType.ALongAndVerboseEnumName;`.

Answer (score 4):

There really is no option apart from mapping the values to a custom static class unless aliasing only the enum name and not its values is acceptable for you as in [James Monger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39858943/767890).

So, the following would work:

```
public static class VerboseMapper
{
     public const ALongClassName.ALongPublicEnumType MyShortName = ALongClassName.ALongPublicEnumType.ALongAndVerboseEnumName;
     ....
}
```

And now you would use `VerboseMapper.MyShortName` instead of the original enum.

Answer (score 1):

To cite from Joseph Albaharis "C# 9.0 in a Nutshell", chapter 2: The using static directive lets you import all the static members of a type so that you can use those members unqualified.
This also works for enums:

using static ALongClassName.ALongPublicEnumType.ALongAndVerboseEnumName;

if (code == Success) { /* */}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** didn't notice the "third party" problem.

The most you can do is `using` an alias for the enum as told in other answers here.

---

You don't really need to put the enum into a class. So the initial part would fall away.

Furthermore, I would say that this is a problem not bound to enums. It is exactly the same as for namespaces, classes, methods, variables and whatever you can attach a name on.

If you don't have terse names maybe there is a semantic/conceptual problem. Like you don't grasp the **SALIENT** part of the values and need to express yourself in this verbose way.

I would try to find short, incisive names, creating this way a glossary for what you are doing.

It really is a problem in your mind because as you know, the code does not care at all how you name those values. Keywords: semantics and saliency.

If you post the names maybe we can come up with shorter names that catch the sense of what you are doing.